# How is Edge So Fast?

Tags: stock-android

I have the BLU STUDIO 5.5 on T-Mobile, however its not a T-Mobile device. I only get Edge. It's pretty slow for video watching. However, it loads sites in less than 2 seconds. Sometimes less than 1. How is that possible? On 4G sometimes I didn't get that, especially when I was throttled after using my complementary LTE data.

Answer (score 3):

Some sites which you recently visited are stored on your browser memory as cache and cookies, so when on slow speed data connection it comes up as a plus point because sites load in a second.

Try this: clear cookies and cache and now try to load the same site on edge. It will take long!

Answer (score 2):

When loading a web page there are two different aspects to the speed. First is how long it takes the beginning of the request and response to traverse the network. This is your latency (usually referred to as "ping time" and measured in milliseconds). Second is how long it takes the bulk of the response to follow. This is your connection speed (usually referred to as "bandwidth" and measured in bits or bytes per second).

If a page is relatively small, just a few tens of kilobytes, then the latency will play a bigger role in the page loading than the bandwidth will, and a "slower" connection could "load" pages faster.